# React Dev Tools | Cannot Update State At All | Chrome Firefox Edge

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools, react-developer-tools

Here are the instructions of downloading React Dev Toools:

`https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/09/02/new-react-developer-tools.html#installation`

I have installed it in all 3 browsers but  it just does not seem to work.

I cannot update the value of any of the `prop` or `state` within the `component` tab React Dev Tools

Image: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AluU7G437QLZlLpM6eoZoSEHdZ9iAg

Can someone tell me what the issue is?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable the edit option, you need to run your development server (localhost), you can't edit states with react devtools in production. I hope help you

Comment: haha yes, I just figured that out just before you posted this.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake I was making was to test it on production.
It's disabled on production.
Most probably due to security purpose.